# Does the Leomund's Tiny Hut spell end currently active magical effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

*Leomund's tiny hut* states :

> [...] Spells and other magical effects can’t extend through the dome or be cast through it [...]

The Beholder's Charm Ray states:

> Eye Rays. The beholder shoots three of the following magical eye rays at random (reroll duplicates), choosing one to three targets it can see within 120 ft. of it:
>
> 1. Charm Ray. The targeted creature must succeed on a DC 16 Wisdom saving throw or be charmed by the beholder for 1 hour, or until the beholder harms the creature.

Would *Leomund's tiny hut* dispell an already active magical effect with a duration such as a beholder's charm ray?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I made a significant edit to your question, feel free to [edit] or revert bits of it. It may help to explain a bit more why you think *Leomund's tiny hut* might end the effect of a Beholder's Charm Ray (is it because you might be extending the effect through the hut?). Also, just for the future, you do not need to specify the game/edition in the actual question since it has the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 5):

### Short Answer: It would do nothing to the charm effect.

While the beholder would not be able to shoot a charm ray into or out of the hut (*Spells and other magical effects can’t extend through the dome or be cast through it*) it doesn't say anything about it preventing/stopping **magical conditions**

**And *Charmed* is considered a [condition](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Conditions#content).**

If this wasn't the case Leomund's Tiny hut would make for an antidote to all sorts of curses, polymorphs, Geas, etc.

In short, it's not an anti-magic field/cure-all magical ills field hospital.

Answer (score 2):

*Leomund's Tiny Hut* is not the same as an **anti magic field**, it does not suppress all magic with its area.

The description, where it talks about *extending through the dome*, is referring to spells with areas of effect. For example, a Wall of Force would not pass through the dome but come right up to the surface of it from one direction and then carry on from the other side, having no effect on the interior at all.
Similarly, Fireball cast at the dome would not pass through into the interior.

In the same vein, spells can't be cast through the dome's wall. I.e. the beholder couldn't Charm someone once they were inside the dome but that doesn't stop magical effects being cast as long as their effects is contained with the dome. A healer could cast some healing spells as long as their target wasn't outside the dome for example.

So, anyone under a magical effect when they went into the dome would still be under that effect while they were in the hut - ignoring other factors that might be relevant (line of sight, for example).